# Как убрать предпросмотр ссылок, отправленных ботом?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, url

Пишу бота на Python. Использую библиотеку pyTelegramBotAPI. Есть вопрос, связанный с отправкой сообщений, в которых имеется ссылка. Как убрать предпросмотр ссылок?

Comment: `disable_web_page_preview = True` https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает!

Comment: @PavelDurmanov спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```
disable_web_page_preview = True
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]